# Trying to parse JSON data from Flickr. Cocoa error 3840

Tags: objective-c, json, ios8, xcode6

I’ve never used an API in conjunction with web services before and I’m having trouble parsing the JSON data I’m receiving from Flickr’s API.  The only thing I do know (from all the things I have read) is that it is easy and very simple.  About as far as I can get is returning a string in the console.  Using a dictionary returns null and or an error. What am I missing?  I want to be able to pull out the id and owner so that I can get the photo url.

This returns data on my photo:

```
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@”%@”, json); //this returns data on my photo
```

This returns null(resultDict) and error 3840:

```
NSString *requestString = @”https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?&method=......etc;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url
  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSMutableDictionary *resultdict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@”%@”, resultDict); //returns null
    If (error != nil) { NSLog(@”%@”, [error localizedDescription]); }
    else { self.myDict = [[resultDict objectforKey:@”photos”] objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSLog(@”%@”, self.myDict); }
}];
[task resume];
```

To check if I have an array of dictionaries I did the following and it returned 0:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainer  error:&error];                                                                                                                                                                                                                          error:&error];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)resultArray.count);
```

Comment: Your usage of "NSError* error" is completely wrong, but that's not the main problem.

Comment: You say you get valid JSON data. But obviously you don't. Show us what you get. 3840 or 3810 - which one is it?

Comment: 3840.. It was a typo.  I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

returns a Dictionary and not an Array of Dictionnaries?

EDIT :

Can you try to use this to request the API please? 
I checked in my projects, my reponses seems to have the same syntax as yours. 
Only the code I use is different.
(If you could give us the full URL you've to call, it would be easier for us ^^')

```
NSString *str=@"YOUR URL";
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error: &error];
NSMutableDictionary* resultList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

I copied it without the errors. I let you manage that ^^

Comment: Looks like an array of 2 dictionaries I believe?.  My json string returns: 2014-11-25 08:54:24.607 Flickr_API[6915:553900] jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":1,"perpage":10,"total":"1","photo":[{"id":"my id #","owner":"my owner #","secret":"secret #","server":"5604","farm":6,"title":"img_43","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
2014-11-25 08:54:24.609 Flickr_API[6915:553900] (null)
2014-11-25 08:54:24.616 Flickr_API[6915:553900] The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

Comment: Looks like a dictionnary with 2 keys: "photos" and "stat"
data[@"photo"] is a NSDictionnary with some keys, and the "photo" key contains another NSDictionnary.

But I don't understand why you can't serialize it

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableDictionary ***resultdict** = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@”%@”, **resultDict**); //returns null
```

resultdict and resultDict are not the same variables. I bet you have an instance variable or a global variable somewhere named resultDict. Instance variables should start with an underscore, among other reasons because it avoids problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

For question maker this answer won't be actual but maybe for them who will face with such problem.
I had the same problem when tried to get data from `flickr.photos.getRecent` method. I forgot to add into URL parametrs value `nojsoncallback=1`.

Without it you get response in JSONP.